# Expand/Collapse table row when multiple number of sections in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here i am trying to create expand/collapse table row.it is working fine with this code in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** only for 1 section:

```
if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
            selectedIndex = -1;
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            return;
        }

        //for table view collapse
        if (selectedIndex != -1) {
            NSIndexPath *prePath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
            selectedIndex = (int)indexPath.row;
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:prePath, nil]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }

        //for non selection
        selectedIndex = (int)indexPath.row;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

through this code i can expand and collapse table row but if and only if for 1 section in table but when multiple section comes it is expanding each sections particular row.so when i click on section 0's 1st row it is going to open all section's 1st row.
How to get rid of this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Tapping on particular section button you can change number of rows.

In section view you have added one button for all section which has common method while tapping.

In tapping method you have to just change bool variable value for particular section

```
    ex.. if sender tag you initials with section number. 
    So For Section 0 button is taped then in tapping method
     if sender.tag == 0  
   { 
       if section0tag
       {
        section0tag = false
       }
       else
       {
        section0tag = true 
       }
      table.reload() ..//Which call number of rows at section data source method
  }

 For number of rowsatSection method data source method

 if section == 0
   {
      if section0tag
        {
            return 5 //Expanding rows
        }
     else
       {
            return  0 //collapsing rows
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method just reload tableview (i.e rOne,rTwo, etc are the bool value):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return rOne ? oneRoundType.count : 0 ;
    }else if (section ==1) {
        return rTwo ? twoRoundType.count : 0 ;
    }else if (section ==2) {
        return rThree ? threeRoundType.count : 0 ;
    }else if (section ==3) {
        return rFour ? fourRoundType.count : 0 ;
    }else if (section ==4) {
        return rFive ? fiveRoundType.count : 0 ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

Global declaration of  sectionIndexToBeExpanded as int to check whether it is expanded or not

```
int sectionIndexToBeExpanded;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   //Assign value 100 to sectionIndexToBeExpanded, if you do not want row expanded 
    sectionIndexToBeExpanded = 100;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [yourArray count];    
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (sectionIndexToBeExpanded==100)  //If not expanded
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (sectionIndexToBeExpanded==section) //If section expand add one more row
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
        return 1;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        if (sectionIndexToBeExpanded==100)    //If section not expanded set value of sectionIndexToBeExpanded to 100
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            [tableView beginUpdates];

            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            sectionIndexToBeExpanded=(int)indexPath.section;

            [tableView endUpdates];

        }
        else if (sectionIndexToBeExpanded==indexPath.section)   // If Section is already expanded at indexpath then collapse ie. delete row
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

             [tableView beginUpdates];

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:sectionIndexToBeExpanded]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            sectionIndexToBeExpanded=100;  //Set section to not expanded

            [tableView endUpdates];
        }
        else   //Expand section
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [tableView beginUpdates];

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:sectionIndexToBeExpanded]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

            //set value of expanded section to sectionIndexToBeExpanded
            sectionIndexToBeExpanded=(int)indexPath.section;

            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

            [tableView endUpdates];

        }

    }

}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```